# Object Compare in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which when loaded sends GET request to server and recives data which will stored in 'master' and i copy that data to 'local' as below.

```
$scope.dirty = false;

init(data);

function init(data) {
    $scope.master = angular.copy(data.data);
    $scope.local = angular.copy($scope.master);
}
```

Now, I use local object as model for my form and I have to button submit and reset. I watch the local object as below.

```
  $scope.$watchCollection('local', function (newLocal, oldLocal) {
    $scope.dirty = !angular.equals(newLocal, $scope.master);
});
```

So, If dirty is true then i can know that data has been modified but since I am using Objects AngularJS adds $$hasKey to `$scope.local` and because of that `$scope.dirty` always sets to true.

So, is there any way to handle this problem? I am new to AngularJS so may be this can be funny question but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was sending data form PHP and PHP treats Number and string as seperate datatype.
So I converted those Number data to string and now It works as desired and also I leart that whenever I use `<form name='newForm>` angularJS creates a new `scope` named `newForm` so that I can you many properties of that scope like `$dirty, $pristinem $submitted and many more.` so Now I dont have to write this logic by myself

Answer (score 1):

You could [convert your object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) to a `JSON` string before comparing:

```
function init(data) {
    // store json data into $scope.master for later comparison
    $scope.master = angular.toJson(data.data);
    $scope.local = angular.copy(data.data);
}

$scope.$watchCollection('local', function (newLocal, oldLocal) {
    var json = angular.toJson(newLocal); // new local without $$ key
    $scope.status.dirty = !angular.equals(json, $scope.master);
    // $scope.local is still a javascript object
});
```

Comment: If I use this code then $scope.local = angular.copy($scope.local) wont work. So, I must use $scope.local = angular.copy(data.data)  right ?

Comment: how so ? you could introduce another variable then?

Comment: What do you mean, it does not work? It does not do what you want, or it throws an error? Plus, in your post, you mention `$scope.dirty` but you have `$scope.status.dirty`, is it a spelling mistake?

Comment: Yes that was my mistake. After using your code `$scope.dirty` still has true value.

Comment: Can you add `console.log()` statements to see the temporary results?

Comment: Does the watch triggers correctly? Is there any specific reason you used `$watchCollection()` instead of  a simple `$watch()` ?

Comment: `dirty: true dirty: false` (new and old values) result of watching dirty. `$watchCollection()` is used for Arrays and Objects.